# express route, check if req.params parameter is empty

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm new to node and express and I would appreciate any help. I'm trying to write a get request which checks if the req.params.address_line is empty and does something if it is, but can't seem to figure out how to do that. So far I have tried this:

```
app.get('/smth/smth_else/:address_line', function(req, res){
  if(req.params.address_line===""){
    res.send("Hello World.")
  }
}
```

This isn't working though so I don't think it is correct. How can I check if the address_line is empty? I googled it extensively, but can't find a working solution. Thanks!

Comment: I guess you're looking for an optional path parameter, try: `/smth/smth_else/:address_line?` (note the `?` at the end).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll have to check first if the whole req.params exists or not

Like this

```
app.get('/smth/smth_else/:address_line', function(req, res){

  if(!req.params)
    return res.send("NO PARAMS PASSED")

  if(!req.params.address_line)
    return res.send("NO address_line PASSED")

  if(req.params.address_line === ""){
    res.send("ADDRESS LINE EMPTY.")
  } else {
    res.send("ADDRESS LINE > ",req.params.address_line)
  }
}
```

Comment: `GET /smth/smth_else` would result in a 404. Thus this request handler will only trigger `res.send("ADDRESS LINE > ",req.params.address_line)`

Answer (score 5):

A potential option is to write a middleware that could create a nice reusable interface for requiring parameters like so:

```js
const requireParams = params => (req, res, next) => {
    const reqParamList = Object.keys(req.params);
    const hasAllRequiredParams = params.every(param =>
        reqParamList.includes(param)
    );
    if (!hasAllRequiredParams)
        return res
            .status(400)
            .send(
                `The following parameters are all required for this route: ${params.join(", ")}`
            );

    next();
};

app.get("/some-route", requireParams(["address_line", "zipcode"]), (req, res) => {
    const { address_line, zipcode } = req.params;
    if (address_line === "") return res.status(400).send("`address_line` must not be an empty string");


    // continue your normal request processing...
});
```

This example makes use of [express middlewares](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html) and [Array.prototype.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every). If you are unfamiliar, these links will provide the relevant documentation for how this works.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple falsy check `!req.params.address_line` for when it is an empty string `""`, `false`, `null`, `undefined`, `0`, or `NaN`.

Comment: It's important to be careful with just checking for falsey values if 0 is a valid value for the parameter. It might be better to explicitly check for `param === undefined`

Answer (score 1):

There are two cases, you need to handle

For unique route names

```
app.get('/smth/smth_else/:address_line', function(req, res){
  if(!req.params){
     res.send("Params Empty!")
  }
}
```

For duplicate route names and multiple params

```
app.get('/smth/smth_else/:address_line1/:address_line2', function(req, res){
  if(Object.keys(req.params).length === 0){
     res.send("Params Empty")
  }
}
```